# How to create art/sprite that will scale well on both 16:9 aspect ratio and 4:3 with a fixed width algorithm that only scale the height?

Tags: drawing, cocos2d-x, scaling

[https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/400932673675329546/642067994347962379/unknown.png?width=678&height=476](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HXFR.png)

Hi guys, I am in a situation that requires some assistant.
First of, I guess I will put the picture here.

So to sum up everything
The programmer who I am working with decided to program the game using Cocos2dx (in 2019 where everyone is using Unity). His design resolution is 720x1280 ( again, in 2019 when everything is 1080p FULL HD)
He has this weird scaling implement to the code
where every single object, gameplay elements, UI are scaled with a fixed width
so on different aspect ratios, only the height will be scaled up and down.
And now he is asking me to draw up sprite and art for the game that would somehow FIT BOTH ASPECT ratio of 16:9 and 4:3 with that weird scaling algorithm of his.
So the question I would like to ask here is: Is it humanly possible for me to do it and if so, how?
Or does the dude just need to rewrite his code and call it the day?
I am no expert in programming and I don't want to claim to be so but I'm pretty sure that is not how you would go about doing this type of scaling.
But if I am wrong, then its clearly as an artist there is sth I didn't yet know :D. So any insight on this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is the job of a UI designer. An artists job is to make it look good on the screen, but the programmer has to make the UI scalable. Have you asked him why he is using cocos opposed to unity instead of complaining to strangers about it? He might have a reason. (I just hope that reason is not 'because I know how it works') Because as you say you have unity and even UnrealEngine4 available. I might be a little biased though, since I am just out of school and know the "leading market" game engines.

Nevertheless, this is not really a question for stackoverflow, but I don't really know where you can ask such a question. Best thing would be to talk to him about it and see why and what is going on.